# PHP's pack("N", $str) in Java

Tags: java, php, pack

I need help with translating this line of PHP into Java `pack( 'N', $data )`

$data should be 7-9 numeric characters, the last being null

I guess it would be packed into a long after going through that function.

which will be pushed through a socket into a server which will run this:

```
byte[] abyte = datagrampacket.getData();
c(abyte, 7, datagrampacket.getLength())
```

and c(...) is the following:

```
public static int c(byte[] abyte, int i, int j) {
    return 0 > j - i - 4 ? 0 : abyte[i] << 24 | (abyte[i + 1] & 255) << 16 | (abyte[i + 2] & 255) << 8 | abyte[i + 3] & 255;
}
```

I guess the function above just expands it back into the original $data

Anyone have any ideas how I "pack" it in java?

EDIT: what it does to the data through php:

```
Stripped Received Data:
array
  0 => string '13231786�' (length=9)
  1 => string '/31/33/32/33/31/37/38/36/0' (length=26) <--- dechex(ord()) for each char above
Packed Data:
array
  0 => string '�Éæª' (length=4)
  1 => string '/0/c9/e6/aa' (length=11) <--- dechex(ord()) for each char above
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of working at this mathematically, I've figured it out.  It's actually pretty simple now that I've figured it out.

in java:

```
int x = (int) Math.floor(j/2^16);
int y = (int) Math.floor((j-(x*65536))/2^8);
int z = (int) Math.floor(j-((x*2^16)+(y*2^8)));

x = 2nd character
y = 3rd character
z = 4th character
```

these numbers are in triple digits so you'd need to convert it to hexadecimal.  Just for reference for anyone who happens to stumble upon this exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use ByteBuffer in a similar way to the [Java gist for PHP/Perl pack/unpack](https://gist.github.com/enrobsop/8403717):

```
static String packN(int value) {
    byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(new Integer(value)).array();
    return new String(bytes, 'UTF-8');
}

static int unpackN(String value) {
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(value.bytes).getInt();
}
```

Comment: The code above starts to fail as the value increases. Please see a [better version written in Groovy](https://gist.github.com/enrobsop/8403667).