# Convert PHP to Java

Tags: java, php

Working on building a Java version of a Putty .ppk reader.

I found a PHP version, but I'm stuck on converting some functionality into Java:

```php
    $password = 'blah';
    $symkey = '';
    $sequence = 0;
    while (strlen($symkey) < 32) {
      $temp = pack('Na*', $sequence++, $password);
      $symkey.= pack('H*', sha1($temp));
    }
    $symkey = substr($symkey, 0, 32);
```

I understand that `$symkey.= pack('H*', sha1($temp));` is calling a sha1 hashing function, and I can do that in java, so that can remain a black-box for this. I'm assuming the `pack('H*')` is just converting the results of the sha1 hash to hex? It's the `pack('Na*'` that I can't grock (or find help with on Google)

Can someone help me, or point me in the right direction?

Thanks so much!

Comment: N stands for long type, a filled with nulles: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.pack.php

Comment: so a null character in java would be: Character.MIN_VALUE I believe? So basically append null characters before my password until it's length long?

Comment: take a look at this SO : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357360/phps-packn-str-in-java

Comment: NULL is not MIN_VALUE

Comment: OH, so what's a null character in java?

Comment: Actually, you want to `hash` text in java, don't you?

Comment: NULL in java is NULL, Like in every language/storage its a 0 Byte / Ascii 0https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character

Comment: Yeah, I believe that's what I did in my answer, mind taking a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this do what I think it will?

```java
final   int             len         =   32;
final   String          pass        =   args[0];
final   StringBuilder   sb          =   new StringBuilder(pass);
                        sb.reverse();
                        sb.setLength(len);
                        sb.reverse();
            System.out.println("len:"+sb.length()+" sb:"+sb);
final   MessageDigest   crypt       =   MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
                        crypt.reset();
final   StringBuilder   sb2         =   new StringBuilder();
            while(sb2.length()<len) {
                        sb2.append(Base64.encodeBase64String(crypt.digest(String.valueOf(sb2).getBytes())));
            }           sb2.setLength(len);
final   String          base64pass  =   String.valueOf(sb2);
            System.out.println(base64pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumin that pack is hashing function :

```
String password = 'blah';
String  symkey  = '';
    int sequence = 0;
    while (symkey.length < 32) {
      String temp = pack("Na*", sequence++, password);
      symkey = pack("H*", sha1(temp));
    }
    symkey = symkey.substring(0, 32);
```

Comment: Sorry no, pack is a language function of PHP, so it's not a black-box.